# Why getting java.io.FileNotFoundException: EISDIR (Is a directory) error?

Tags: java, android, kotlin

I try to create a file in the project directory and write my logs in it but when I try to create a file I got `open failed: EISDIR (is a directory)`

Here is my **edited** code

```
        val directoryPath =applicationContext.filesDir.absolutePath.toString()+"/logs/"
        val directory = File(directoryPath)

        if (!directory.exists()) {
            directory.mkdirs()
        }

        val fileName = "Logs.txt"

        val file = File(directory , fileName)
        val fos = FileOutputStream(file)
        fos.write("$i) $message\n".toByteArray(Charsets.UTF_8))
        fos.flush()
        fos.close()
```

NOTE : I tried also `file.parentFile` or `file.createNewFile()` too

Comment: Did you set and grant READ_EXTERNAL_STORAGE and WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE permissions?

Comment: @LucaPizzini yes

Comment: Try to declare your directory as `val file = File(applicationContext.filesDir, "/logs")` or `val file = File(applicationContext.filesDir, "logs")`

Comment: if (outFile.isDirectory()) outFile.delete();

Comment: @LucaPizzini edited code same error...

Comment: @blackapps edited code same error

Comment: Then add it to your code so we can see what you do. Further you should check the return value of mkdir and stop if it returns false. Please adapt your code.

Comment: @blackapps i tried your suggession but its same error

Comment: Add the proposed code to your post so we can see what you do. Adapt the mkdir stuff. Second time i ask.

Comment: @blackapps added

Comment: `try to create a file in project directory` That is not the project directory. The project directory is on your PC and in use by Android Studio.

Comment: You have added nothing of the things i asked for. I see nothing of the things i asked you to do.

Comment: @blackapps 'The project directory is on your PC and in use by Android Studio' that is where i want to write file

Comment: So your pc is at home. And you are with your phone in town at friends. And then you want your app to create a file on your pc?

Comment: @blackapps i just try to create real eligible file for my logs.. thats it

Comment: @blackapps not in external storage

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Looks like you somehow created a directory with this name in the past (rather than a file), and now that you are trying to open it and write to it you get an error.

Try deleting this directory first and then rerun your code.

Comment: is it useful to change directory name also?

Comment: yes, you can try that, too. As long as you are sure that there is no existing directory with the same path and name as the file you are trying to create it should work

Comment: as you explained code worked but i can't find folder in my directory...

Comment: You are probably using internal storage of your app, you can't see these files using a regular file manager on your device

Comment: You can use Android Studio's built in device [file explorer](https://developer.android.com/studio/debug/device-file-explorer)
Or you can list all the files and folders in your path using this code:

File directory = new File(directory);
File[] files = directory.listFiles();
Log.d("Files", "Size: "+ files.length);
for (int i = 0; i < files.length; i++)
{
    Log.d("Files", "FileName:" + files[i].getName());
}

Comment: If you meant you need to check your Log.txt file, you can simply read it similarly to how you wrote to it, and log its contents